# Bitbucket Slack settings page not opening

Tags: bitbucket, slack, bitbucket-cloud

I am using slack and bitbucket. I have successfully installed bitbucket integration on slack. But no notification comes. So I want to change notification settings in Bitbucket. But Repository Settings->Slack Settings page not opening.

The following screen always comes up. How can I fix this problem.

Also I ask a question in Bitbucket community but no one answering.

[image]